# .NET unit test framework that can handle tests with more than one thread

Tags: .net, multithreading, testing

I'm trying to find a unit test framework, for the .NET platform, that can handle tests with more than one thread.

NUnit does not supports tests that spanws threads, since, for example, exceptions in those threads are not taked into consideration. There is an extension by Roy Osherove, but it is quite dated [1](http://weblogs.asp.net/rosherove/archive/2007/06/22/multi-threaded-unit-tests-with-osherove-threadtester.aspx).

MBUnit allows a test to be concurrently executed by many threads, however I don't know if it supports threads that are created inside a thread. For instance, to test a concurrent collection, I want different kinds of threads (producer threads and consumer threads) running simultaneous. Having multiple threads executing the *same* test code is not enough.

Thanks
Pedro

Comment: I think the result of unit tests should be reproducable. The thing with multithreading is, that the occurence of race conditions and other timing issues is highly dependent on the environment where the test case is running. So this sounds a bit contradictory to me.

Comment: @Jan I agree you'd need enormous control to be able to reproduce. Running a threaded unit test would mean the testing framework has to completely take over threading/scheduling from Windows, and you'd have to specify each combination of interruptions explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that your main issue is that exceptions that do not happen on the  "test thread" (i.e. the main thread) do not result in test failure.

The fact that these exceptions are ignored can be controlled somewhat. I explain this issue in a blog post in terms of the ReSharper test runner, but the same fix applies to the NUnit runner:

[ReSharper test runner – hidden thread exceptions](http://gojisoft.com/blog/2010/05/14/resharper-test-runner-hidden-thread-exceptions/)

The key is configuring [legacyUnhandledExceptionPolicy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228965.aspx) for the executable that is running the tests.